# SFTP error handling in shell script

Tags: shell, error-handling, scripting, sftp

I am writing a SH-script that downloads a file from an SFTP server.
I want to recognize if any error appears during the SFTP connection of my script.
But **without redirecting my outputs and neither using grep** because I already redirect my outputs to different log files.

I try to make a command similar to the below example but I need the `{---?---}` parts.
I use a `case` syntax for example, but I can use `if`, or any other syntaxes.

```
sftp <user>@<host>:<remote_file> <local_destination>

if [ $? != 0 ];
    then
        case {---?---} in
            {---?---})
                _error_exit "permission denied, please try again"
                ;;
            {---?---})
                _error_exit "SFTP server not responding, maybe offline"
                ;;
            {---?---})
                _error_exit "file not found"
                ;;
            *)
                _error_exit "unable to download the file from SFTP server"
        esac
    else
        _status "file downloaded"
    fi
}
```

Comment: What I do is setup conditions to force the error I want to trap, run scp from cmd line, and then `echo $?` to see what the return value is.  Assign the scp return value to a separate variable, and then use it in the case statement, like `scp .... ; scp_rc=$? ; case ${scp_rc} in 0 ) echo "all OK" ;; 1 ) _err_ex "cond 1" ;; _err_ex "cond 2" ;; * ) _err_ex "unknown cond $scp_rc" ;; esac` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenSSH `sftp` command has only two exit codes, `0` for success and `1` for failure.

So if you need to distinguish different errors, parsing the command output is your only way.

You can redirect `sftp` command output to a temporary file, parse the temp file to find an error message and then print the temp file to output, so that it is included into your log too.

```
sftp ... > /tmp/sftp.log
grep ... /tmp/sftp.log
...
cat /tmp/sftp.log
```